# How to copy nginx logs of requests that took more than n seconds

Tags: nginx, kong

Consider that the access logs are of this format:

> log_format  detailed  '$remote_addr $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
>                             '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
>                             '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for" '
>                             '$request_length $request_time $upstream_connect_time $upstream_header_time $upstream_response_time';

How can I have a new log file that contains only requests that took more than 5 seconds?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with built in `if` statemen on `access_log` directive like so:

```
http{
...
map $upstream_response_time $under {
   ~^[01234]\.[0-9]+ 1; 
   default 0; 
   } 

server {
   set $over 1;
   if ( $under = 1 ) { set $over 0; }
   access_log /some/folder/under.log combined if=$under;
   access_log /some/folder/over.log combined if=$over;
   ...
   }
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can send logs to http-log and process them to figure out if anything is more than the time you are expecting it to.

Stopping logs based on some condition looks little complex to implement. But once logs are generated, extracting the required info from them seems correct approach.